# Passing optional @objc enum type into @objc protocol

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I'm trying to create an optional function in @objc protocol, The documentType is @objc enum as well. But I'm getting this error:

> Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter cannot
> be represented in Objective-C

My source code:

```
@objc enum DocumentType: Int {
    case pdf
    case png
}

@objc protocol ImageDocumentEditorProtocol: class {
    @objc optional func imageDocumentEditorDidCancel(documentType: DocumentType?)
}
```

How can I solve this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective-C doesn't have optional enums. Enums must be non-optional. Classes can be optional, not enums :(

One workaround is to add a case:

```
@objc enum DocumentType: Int {
    case pdf
    case png
    case none
}
```

And use the non-optional type `DocumentType` instead.

Of course, this makes non-optional `DocumentType`s non-representable. To represent both optional and non-optional `DocumentType`s, you would need two types:

```
@objc enum DocumentType: Int {
    case pdf
    case png
    
    func asOptionalDocumentType() -> OptionalDocumentType {
        switch self {
        case .pdf: return .pdf
        case .png: return .png
        }
    }
}

extension Optional where Wrapped == DocumentType {
    func asOptionalDocumentType() -> OptionalDocumentType {
        self?.asOptionalDocumentType() ?? .none
    }
}

@objc enum OptionalDocumentType: Int, ExpressibleByNilLiteral {
    
    case pdf
    case png
    case none
    
    func asDocumentType() -> DocumentType? {
        switch self {
        case .pdf: return .pdf
        case .png: return .png
        case .none: return nil
        }
    }
    
    init(nilLiteral: ()) {
        self = .none
    }
}
```

I have added conversion methods to make it easy to convert between them, but they are not technically needed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `?`.

In Objective-C, you cannot represent an Optional of primitive types.

Make it non-Optional, or find another way.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the optional on the DocumentType so the function will be:

`@objc optional func imageDocumentEditorDidCancel(documentType: DocumentType)`

if you want to have something representing the nil value here you can add another case in the enum for it like this:

```
@objc enum DocumentType: Int {
    case pdf
    case png
    case none
}
```